# ¿Cómo generar sentencias sql automáticamente?

Tags: sql, oracle-11g

Se requiere ejecutar unas sentencias DCL(Data Control Language) repetitivas sobre ciertas tablas en base da datos. ¿Cómo puedo generarlas automáticamente?

Sentencia a generar:

```
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON NOMBRETABLA TO ADMINISTRADOR;
```

Se debe aplicar sobre todas las tablas que incian con FAM_

Resultado esperado despues de ejecutar la consulta:

```
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON FAM_TABLA_A TO ADMINISTRADOR;
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON FAM_TABLA_B TO ADMINISTRADOR;
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON FAM_PRUEBA TO ADMINISTRADOR;
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON FAM_TABLAC TO ADMINISTRADOR;
```

**Actualizaciones:**

Utilizar un select para concatenar `GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON`  con el nómbre de todas las tablas que incian con FAM_

...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primera idea: pon las tablas que necesitas trabajar en una tabla nueva, digamos que se llame `listatablas` y luego ejecuta algo como

```sql
SELECT 'GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON ' || lt.tabla || ' TO ADMINISTRADOR;'
FROM listatablas lt
```

Segunda idea: si posees los permisos suficientes con el usuario con que te conectas a tu base de datos, puedes obtener todas las tablas desde la vista [`dba_tables`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4155.htm#REFRN23286):

```sql
SELECT 'GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON ' || table_name || ' TO ADMINISTRADOR;'
FROM dba_tables
WHERE table_name LIKE 'FAM_%'
```

Si tu usuario no tiene los permisos suficientes, podrías utilizar [`all_tables`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2105.htm#REFRN20286)  en lugar de `dba_tables`:

```sql
SELECT 'GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON ' || table_name || ' TO ADMINISTRADOR;'
FROM all_tables
WHERE table_name LIKE 'FAM_%'
```

Basado en: [Get list of all tables in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/205736/1065197)

Comment: Probando idea dos... pero sale este error: "ora-00909: número de argumentos no válido"

Comment: Corregido. Estaba utilizando la sintaxis de MySQL (error mío). Acabo de colocarlo en sintaxis de Oracle.

Comment: Funciona perfectamente!. Gracias!!!

Comment: De nada........

Comment: Por si acaso, los puntos seguidos es para completar los 15 caracteres que piden de requisito para postear el comentario.